# Sending hash values to controller from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you send a @user hash to a controller? I'm trying to create a user from a view that already has some values in @customer to a "create" in a controller. But it's giving me undefined method `permit' for nil:NilClass for my params.require(...) I've looked around everywhere on this website as well as others and read books and have been working on it for 3 days now.. I'm a super newbie. Thanks in advance.

In my view:

```
link_to "Add User", users_path(@user), method: :post
```

In my controller:

```
def user_params
 params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
```

Comment: you are trying to copy the user record to a new record by link_to method ?

Comment: There are no need to send user hash to controller,  you can pass user_id to controller and get other details there

Comment: Yeah. And I forgot to mention, that this is from a different view, not from the user controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass params in link_to:

```
link_to "Add User", users_path(@user,:user => {:name => @user.name,:email => @user.email} ), method: :post
```

Check It is work for me

Comment: Thanks, but it's still giving me the same nil error.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to copy of the user then I suggest create a new method in the users_controller.rb

```
def clone_user
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  new_user = user.dup
  new_user.save
  redirect_to root_path #whatever path you need 
end
```

Add this on routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  collection do 
    post :clone_user
  end
end

link_to "Add User", clone_user_user_path(id: @user.id), method: :post
```

Comment: This is cool. Thank you for your reply. I'll study your code and incorporate this as well.